# How to get data from array of object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below `data` is printed in `console.log` , How can i print header from this array i tried below approach but i got error map is not a function, So this is server side `nodejs` , How can i get `headers` object from `data` ?

server.js

```
console.log(data);

var result = data.map(function(a) {return a.fieldName;});

    { file:
       [ { fieldName: 'file',
           originalFilename: 'sco_poc.bpmn',
           path: 'yGCNPv.bpmn',
           headers: [Object],
           size: 11078 } ] }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
console.log(data.file[0].headers);
```

try this

OR This

```
var result = data.file.map(function(a) {
       console.log(a.headers);
        return a.headers;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve above problem also using Lodash.

Here is an example:

```
 var result = _.map(data.file,function(value){
    return value.headers;
 });

 console.log(result);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Simran37/12daLc2r/)